# want to group the person by lastname, firstsname, middlename, age, sex and birthday and count how many times they appear in the list

Tags: c#, linq

```
        var spesbabies = new List<SpesBabies>();

        var placed = (from ben in db.Beneficiaries
                      join reg in db.Registrations on ben.ID equals reg.BenID
                      join plc in db.Placements on reg.ID equals plc.RegID
                   
                      select new 
                      {
                          LastName = ben.LastName,
                          FirstName = ben.FirstName,
                          MiddleName = ben.MiddleName,
                          Sex = ben.Gender,
                          BirthDate = ben.BirthDate,
                          Age = (int)plc.Age,

                      }).ToList();
```

im  expecting like this:

| LastName | FirstName | MiddleName | Age | Gender | Birthdate | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dela Cruz | Jose | Chan | 23 | Male | 04/23/1999 | 1 |
| Chan | Joey | Salceda | 25 | Male | 08/26/1998 | 2 |

Comment: There’s an example of grouping by an anonymous type [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results#group-by-anonymous-type)

Comment: You haven't shown what you've tried in terms of grouping. If you show how you're trying to group, then we can help find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var spesbabies = new List<SpesBabies>();

var placed = (from ben in db.Beneficiaries
join reg in db.Registrations on ben.ID equals reg.BenID
join plc in db.Placements on reg.ID equals plc.RegID)
.GroupBy( x => new {x, x.Firstname, x.MiddleName, x.Gender, x.BirthDate, x.Age})
.Select(x =>  new
{
    LastName = x.Key.LastName,
    FirstName = x.Key.FirstName,
    MiddleName = x.Key.MiddleName,
    Sex = x.Key.Gender,
    BirthDate = x.Key.BirthDate,
    Age = (int)x.Key.Age,
    Count = x.Count()
}).ToList();
```

Be careful with big grouping like this, the performance will not be great.

Comment: It is non compilable answer. Follow query. syntax to the rest of the query. Use formatting,

Comment: i tried it but sorry sir its no compilable

Comment: Edited. My apologies. I thought of giving an idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var Grouped = placed.GroupBy(x => new { x.LastName, x.FirstName, x.MiddleName, x.Sex, x.BirthDate, x.Age })
                                .Select(x => new SpesBabies
                                {
                                    LastName = x.Key.LastName,
                                    FirstName = x.Key.FirstName,
                                    MiddleName = x.Key.MiddleName,
                                    Sex = x.Key.Sex,
                                    BirthDate = x.Key.BirthDate,
                                    Age = x.Key.Age,
                                    Count = x.Count()
                                }).ToList();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).